# Travis CI Python failed to import 'requests'

Tags: python, python-requests, travis-ci

I would like to run a simple Python 3 script in the Travis CI build environment.
I followed the Travis CI Python guide (https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/python) to create an initial `.travis.yml` file.

Travis CI runs each build in a separate virtualenv against the Python versions described in the YML file.

My script depends on the `requests` module, I added it to the `requirements.txt` file and pip installs it in Travis CI, but as soon as the script runs, the script can't import the module.

**error**

```
./benchmark.py https://graph.irail.be/sncb/connections -n 10 -i -o results.csv
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./benchmark.py", line 3, in <module>
   import requests
ImportError: No module named 'requests'
```

**.travis.yml**

```
language: python
python:
   - "3.3"
   - "3.4"
   - "3.5"
   - "3.6"
# command to install deps
install:
   - pip install -r requirements.txt

# run build
script:
   - ./benchmark.py https://graph.irail.be/sncb/connections -n 10 -i -o results.csv
```

My Github repo: https://github.com/DylanVanAssche/http-benchmark/tree/feature/CI

My Travis CI build: https://travis-ci.com/DylanVanAssche/http-benchmark/jobs/145320050

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specifically call `python3 <filename>` to make sure you're using python3. I'm not sure why this happens but apparently the `#!/usr/bin/python3` directive is not sufficient to load the proper modules.

Comment: Hmm, what if you specifically launch with `python3 <filename>` rather than `./filename`. I feel like I've run into this issue before and explicitly calling python3 fixed it.

Comment: Thanks! That was the cause of my build failure. If you update your answer I will accept it and close this one!

Comment: so it is both `python` and the path issue?

Comment: You need to call the Python interpreter (`python3 myscript.py`) before your file. The shebang line (`#!/usr/bin/python3`) isn't working apparently in Travis CI.